# Issue using width in css custom

Tags: html, css

I created a invoice table

but on the top where it says:

```
RUC N° 20516223163
     INVOICE
  N° 001- 0004
```

Is not showing in the middle and more bigger to the left because this is taking 2 spaces

```
<th class="smal"colspan="2">DESCRIPTION</th>
```

Here is the demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/g78q9/27/

I'm doing this image[image]

Please somebody can help me?

Comment: Please don't highlight fiddle links

Comment: And do you need something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/g78q9/28/

Comment: I want to do like the image in the same position

Comment: IMHO - you should consider using `<div>` tags for the header instead of a table. Tables are really for data only (which could work for the body of this invoice). Just a thought

Comment: Look at this please http://jsfiddle.net/g78q9/32/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood what you want, try this changes:

Increase your colspans by "1" on the `trick` td, and on all Descriptions tds.

Also, to prevent the Nº of breaking to the next line, add `white-space: nowrap` the the `td.trick` class.

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g78q9/29/

Comment: ok this is your example look please http://jsfiddle.net/g78q9/33/ at the end is not working in total

Comment: Just adjust the total's colspans as well... From "4" to "5". http://jsfiddle.net/g78q9/37/

Comment: Ok  seems you got it but I have a last question how can I do to show td without writing something like point because if i remove the point won't show the TD

Comment: There are some tricks for that. Most would involve changing your layout. But a very rustic way is to add a `height` value to your `td.small` class: http://jsfiddle.net/g78q9/41/

Comment: You are a master designer =)

Comment: But is there any other way to create tr and td without repeating several times like my example?

Comment: Yes. You have to use some kind of programming language. Perhaps the best way would be Javascript...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56435/discussion-between-carlitos-morales-and-lcsalazar).

Answer (score 2):

in your td css you have to change to % not px

```
td.trick {
  width: 40%;
```

you have to change like this and it will show like you want, hope helped you :-D

Comment: It increased but my columns Punit and import are not according the image http://jsfiddle.net/g78q9/38/